# Calculate Percentage difference among values and create groups

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark, data-science

[image]

Isthere any python library available which can help us to perform all the actions shown in picture? Does this fall under data science category?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your case you compare one value yo the previous value and assigned it to a group. If that’s the case
You can use numpy library
Create an array then calculate the percentage difference between each value and the previous value. Then create groups based on the percentage difference.

Comment: Hello Magedo , I am comparing one value for eg DNB with all the remaining values  and that is how I am creating matrix . Can I use numpy for that ?

Comment: Yes you can brother. 
Also you need to use pandas for data frame and creating group

Answer (score 0):

You can get the groups using combinations from itertools:

```
def pctDiff(A,B):
    return abs(A-B)*200/(A+B)

from itertools import combinations

D = {"DNB":5000, "SME":7000, "ZIM":10000, "PRIVCO":15000, "ZI":8000, "ES":500}

groups = [(a,b) for a,b in combinations(D,2) if pctDiff(D[a],D[b]) < 30]

print(groups)
# [('SME', 'ZI'), ('ZIM', 'ZI')]
```

You could also use numpy (but unless you have very large datasets, it may be a bit overkill):

```
import numpy as np

names  = np.array(["DNB", "SME", "ZIM", "PRIVCO", "ZI", "ES"])
prices = np.array([5000, 7000, 10000, 15000, 8000, 500])

A,B    = prices[:,None],prices[None,:]    # vertical/horizontal to broadcast
diffs  = np.triu(abs(A-B)*200/(A+B))      # np.triu is to avoid duplicates

a,b    = np.where((0<diffs) & (diffs<30)) # selection

groups = [*zip(names[a],names[b])]        # name pairs

print(groups)

[('SME', 'ZI'), ('ZIM', 'ZI')]
```

Or without any imports:

```
names  = ["DNB", "SME", "ZIM", "PRIVCO", "ZI", "ES"]
prices = [5000, 7000, 10000, 15000, 8000, 500]

groups = [(a,b) for (i,a),A in zip(enumerate(names,1),prices)
                for b,B in zip(names[i:],prices[i:])
                if abs(A-B)*200/(A+B) < 30 ]    

print(groups)

# [('SME', 'ZI'), ('ZIM', 'ZI')]
```

Comment: Thank you Alain for complete end to end code. Is there way we can get names along with prices ?

Comment: Sure,  `= [(a,D[a],b,D[b]) ...` for first example,  `= [*zip(names[a],prices[a],names[b],prices[b])]` for second example and `= [(a,A,b,B) ...` for last one.

Comment: Hello @alain If my input is like `{'v1_rev': 3000, 'v2_rev': 4444, 'v3_rev': 66, 'v4_rev': 234534, 'v5_rev': 5665, 'v6_rev': 66, 'v7_rev': 66}` I want output to be like 
`[('v2_rev', 'v5_rev'), ('v3_rev', 'v6_rev','v7_rev')]`